# How to trigger custom python code when a valid django form is saved in the database

Tags: python, django, forms

Django newbie here, I created a simple form following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XOS_UpJirU) tutorial, and my form correctly saves the data in my Postgres connected local database. I was wondering, how can I trigger a function, whenever a valid form is saved into the database? The code I want to run is a simple function which is written in a python file, and it does some processing on the latest data given by the first form. I want it to run only when a valid form data is saved and was wondering if django signal trigger is my way to go. Feel free to ask for any further clarification. In other words, **I want to do some post-processing on data, which is present inside the database, which is being filled by the form, and trigger the post-processing only when valid data is entered in the database**.

Here is my code :

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import auditform, ClientAuditForm
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from . import rocode



# def auditingfun(request):
#     return HttpResponse('Auditing form works')
# # Create your views here.

def auditingfun(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        forminput = auditform(request.POST)
        if forminput.is_valid():

            Name = forminput.cleaned_data['Name']
            Origin = forminput.cleaned_data['Origin']
            ClientAddress = forminput.cleaned_data['ClientAddress']
            DispatchType = forminput.cleaned_data['DispatchType']
            ETA = forminput.cleaned_data['ETA']
            GSTIN = forminput.cleaned_data['GSTIN']
            # print(GSTIN,Name,Origin,Destination,MaterialType,Preference,ClientAddress,DispatchType,ETA)

    forminput = auditform(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'auditing/auditform.html', {'forminput': forminput} )
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import auditModel

class auditform(forms.Form):
    Origin = forms.CharField()
    Destination = forms.CharField()
    MaterialType = forms.CharField()
    Preference = forms.CharField()
    ClientAddress = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    Name = forms.CharField()
    GSTIN = forms.IntegerField()
    DispatchType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('Question','Inbound'),('Other','Outbound')])
    ETA = forms.CharField()


class ClientAuditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = auditModel
            fields = ('Origin','Destination','MaterialType','GSTIN','Name','Preference','ClientAddress','DispatchType','ETA')
```

Just for simplicity, imagine the customcode (imported in the views.py file as rocode.py) I have just adds the data entered and stores the data in the same database, in a different column.

Comment: could answer this but if you're a newbie.. look up django signals

Comment: @bryan60 I am a newbie, but I will be able to look up or research on whatever I need to do to get this done. So give me what you got :)

Comment: i mean i'll copy and paste more or less from the django docs but sure why not

Comment: Does your code currently succeed in actually saving the form to the database?
It doesn't seem like it's doing that at all in the code that you pasted?

Comment: Did you try to make it work using `ClientAuditForm` and then switched to `auditform` in an attempt to make it work? It would be more helpful to post your "working" code, and then any attempts separately.

Comment: @Geekfish My code does save the data in the database, do you want to see the models.py file ? This is my working code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to use here is signals.  A signal is some function that gets executed after an item is added or updated in your data base. Assuming your model you want to connect to is called "MyModel" do this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # run your custom code HERE
```

instance is what was inserted / updated, created is boolean indicating if this was an update or insert.

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/

Comment: Why use a signal at all? Signals are for allowing extension / dealing with behaviours one cannot easily override (ex. 3rd party packages/django internals), or apply to many different places.

Also, if what is desired is post-processing, shouldn't this be `post_save`  instead?

Comment: signals are for post processing (yes should be post save, copy paste error)

Comment: To clarify, I think overriding the form's or model's `save` is probably much easier/cleaner.

Comment: the purpose is separation of responsibilities and clear maintainable code. the form save method is for getting the item into the database.  post processing (eg pre caching, updating a search index, sending notifications, calling a webhook, things that are sort of extra to the actual save) is the signals use case.

Comment: I see what you mean, and I agree with the principles! However one could argue that signal is a very "indirect" place to do that a lot of the time.
1) My suspicion here is that what he actually wants is *pre*-processing, so altering the data before he saves it. 2) But even if he wants *post*-processing, then maybe it's ok to just trigger a regular function after saving the form (clean intent, still separate and can go into say, a caching/search/notification module...)

Comment: 1. agreed the intent is't super clear, but he seemed to ask for post processing (even if it's not what he actually wants) so that's what I gave.  2. I could see arguments either way but this is generally how I build my apps and have seen success. save functions get the things in, signals handle post processing and the like.

Comment: @Geekfish Another reason is that sometimes things can get updated or inserted in ways other than the form save method. This method gurantees essential post processing runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190521/discussion-between-geekfish-and-bryan60).

Comment: @Geekfish My intention was post-processing. I want the data to be stored in the database, and then do some processing on it. I think it was clear in the question, but I will reframe it nonetheless

Comment: @bryan60 Erm...can you help me out a bit...what do I put in place of  `sender, instance, created, **kwargs`  ?? and where does the function `my_handler` run ? And where does this whole code stay inside of ? views.py or models.py ?

Comment: Please read the documentation provided. Nothing goes in place of those arguments. They are the arguments to the receiver. You can put it where ever you like. Putting it in models is usually easy.