# Do some post-processing after form submit, and render a new page with the newly processed data

Tags: python, django, forms, signals, post-processing

Django newbie here, I created a simple form following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XOS_UpJirU) tutorial, and my form correctly saves the data in my Postgres connected local database. Then I used a signal to trigger on post_save so I can run my custom code. I learned by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304452/how-to-trigger-custom-python-code-when-a-valid-django-form-is-saved-in-the-datab). **Now, after the user enters data in the form and it gets saved, which triggers the custom code which does some post-processing, I want to show the user a new page with the newly processed data.** But the trigger function I have used does not let me pass arguments to the custom code function. Before this, I was able to show the user the new page with some sample data and render a page with the new data. But, now I want to do it only when a user enters some data. Is this the right approach ? My templates all work fine, and the custom code fills the variables like `rocode.vehicleroute` with string values.

Here is my code :

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import auditform, ClientAuditForm
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import auditModel


def clientauditingfun(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forminput = ClientAuditForm(request.POST)
        if forminput.is_valid():

            Preference = forminput.cleaned_data['Preference']
            ClientAddress = forminput.cleaned_data['ClientAddress']
            DispatchType = forminput.cleaned_data['DispatchType']
            ETA = forminput.cleaned_data['ETA']
            print("Data saved succesfully")
            forminput.save()

    forminput = ClientAuditForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'auditing/auditform.html', {'forminput': forminput} )

def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("trigger running")
    if created:
        from . import rocode
        import itertools

        print("function my_handler running inside")

        rocode.main() # this is my custom code which fills the values of all the variables given below
        data1 = list(itertools.zip_longest(rocode.vehicleroute, rocode.routepath, rocode.routeduration, rocode.routeETA,
                                           rocode.routedistance, rocode.routelink, rocode.routetotaldistance))
        return render( '','auditing/routput.html', {'data': data1})



post_save.connect(receiver=my_handler, sender=auditModel)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import auditModel


class ClientAuditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = auditModel
            fields = ('Origin','Destination','MaterialType','GSTIN','Name','Preference','ClientAddress','DispatchType','ETA')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class auditModel(models.Model):
    Origin = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Destination = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    MaterialType =  models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Preference = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    ClientAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    GSTIN = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    DispatchType = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    ETA = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)


    def _str_(self):
        return self.Origin
```

Here is the function I used to run the custom code, but it ran all the time being in the views.py file, and it was rendering the page perfectly. But, now all I want is to run only when a post_save trigger is signalled.

```
def read_file(request):
  import itertools

  data1 = list(itertools.zip_longest(rocode.vehicleroute, rocode.routepath, rocode.routeduration, rocode.routeETA,
                                   rocode.routedistance, rocode.routelink,
                                   rocode.routetotaldistance))
  return render(request, "input.html", {'data': data1})
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the right approach. Signals can't turn responses to the client, so there is no point rendering a template there.

You should redirect after saving to a new URL which takes the id of the newly created object and display the template from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, so do you mean I should redirect the user to a new page with a custom generated code ID in the URL and display the processed data there ? Damn... what have I forsaken upon myself! BTW any tutorial or guide which does this ? It seems similar to ecommerce cart logic...