# Django: Method to execute after "clean" in admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Fairly simple: Which method can be overwritten after "clean" method? I am using "clean" to verify an uploaded image and once I confirmed it is ok and saved, I want to switch it using some external API:

```
class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ["name", "file",]
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FooAdminForm, self).clean()
        ...
        return cleaned_data

    def bar(self):
        # do stuff with new data in database


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "file",]
    form = FooAdminForm
```

is there some method `bar` that can do what I need? Or do I have to wrestle with a signal (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304452/how-to-trigger-custom-python-code-when-a-valid-django-form-is-saved-in-the-datab))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ModelAdmin` class has a method [`save_model` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) which is called to save the model instance, so you can override that if needed:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "file",]
    form = FooAdminForm
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        # Do something with `obj`
```